# Check if data exists in another table on insert?

Tags: sql, constraints

```
Table A
(
Table_A_ID int
)

Table B
(
Table_B_ID int
Value int
)
```

Say I want to insert data into Table B, where 'Value' would be the same as a Table_A_ID.
How would I make a constraint or check that the data actually exists in the table on insertion?

Comment: Look up foreign key and foreign key constraint

Comment: Which DB are you using? mysql, sql server, oracle, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to enforce data integrity not only on INSERT into Table B, but also on UPDATE and DELETE in both tables.

Anyway options are:

1. [FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) on Table B
2. [TRIGGER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger)s on both tables
3. As a last resort if for some reason 1 and 2 is not an option [STORED PROCEDURE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure)s for all insert, delete update operations for both tables

The **preferred** way to go in most cases is FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT.

Answer (score 0):

Yap, I agree with @peterm.

Cause, if your both `Table_A_ID` and `Table_B_Id` are primary keys for both tables, then you don't even need two tables to store the `value`. Since, your two tables are seems to be on 'one-to-one' relationship. It's one of the database *integrity* issues.

I think you didn't do proper normalisation for this database.
Just suggesting a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this example](http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/) which demonstrates how to setup a foreign key constraint.

#### Create employee table

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
    firstname varchar(30),
    lastname varchar(30),
    birthdate date,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY idx_lastname (lastname)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

#### Create borrowed table

```
CREATE TABLE borrowed (
    ref int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    employeeid smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
    book varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (ref)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

#### Add a constraint to borrowed table

```
ALTER TABLE borrowed
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_borrowed
FOREIGN KEY (employeeid) REFERENCES employee(id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

**NOTE:** This tells MySQL that we want to alter the `borrowed table` by adding a constraint called `‘FK_borrowed’`. The `employeeid column` will reference the `id column` in the `employee table` – in other words, an employee must exist before they can borrow a book.

The final two lines are perhaps the most interesting. They state that if an employee ID is updated or an employee is deleted, the changes should be applied to the `borrowed table`.

**NOTE:** See the above URL for more details, this is just an excerpt from that article!

Answer (score 0):

Create a foreign key constraint on the column 'Value' on table B that references the 'Table_A_ID' column.

Doing this will only allow values that exist in table A to be added into the 'Value' field of table B.

To accomplish this you first need to make Table_A_ID column the primary key for table A, or it at least has to have some sort of unique constraint applied to it to be a foreign key candidate.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION -- REMOVE TRANSACTION AND ROLLBACK AFTER DONE TESTING    

--PUT A PRIMARY KEY ON TABLE A
CREATE TABLE A 
( Table_A_ID int CONSTRAINT PK_A_Table_A_ID PRIMARY KEY)

--ON VALUE ADD A FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT THAT REFERENCEs TABLE A
CREATE TABLE B
( Table_B_ID int,
  [Value] int CONSTRAINT FK_B_Value_A REFERENCES A(Table_A_ID)
)

-- TEST VALID INSERT
INSERT A (Table_A_ID) VALUES (1)
INSERT B (Table_B_ID, [Value]) VALUES (1,1)

--NOT ALLOW TO INSERT A VALUE THAT DOES NOT EXIST IN A
--THIS WILL THROW A FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT ERROR
INSERT B (Table_B_ID, [Value]) VALUES (1,2) -- 2 DNE in table A

ROLLBACK
```

Note: there is no magic to 'FK_B_Value_A' or 'PK_A_Table_A_ID' it simply a naming convention and be called anything. The syntax on the foreign key and primary key lines work like this:

*column-definition* CONSTRAINT *give-the-constraint-a-name* REFERENCES *table-name* ( *table-column* )

*column-definition* CONSTRAINT *give-the-constraint-a-name* PRIMARY KEY